# How to place text on image with nodejs without use of third-party libraries

Tags: node.js, image-processing

Please explain, how can I add some text to the image with nodejs. I googled all day but didn't find a solution other than using libraries. Why is this done in php with one line of code, but with nodejs you need bunch of third-party code to be imported to your server? Thank you.

Comment: "using libraries" is how that's usually done. do you expect image processing, or text drawing, to be part of the javascript language itself? even php uses libraries. they're just commonly shipped with php, and the docs are integrated. node.js is a lot more fragmented.

Comment: "even php uses libraries. they're just commonly shipped with php" - that means their creator won't stop supporting them in a year, right? But there are no such libraries for nodejs. So what to do? Rely on a library that has many stars to date? @Christoph Rackwitz